# Pandas: Using the tilde operator to return inverse data with two filters

Tags: python, pandas

I'm filtering on two DataFrame columns using `isin`. Aim is to return two distinct DataFrames: One where the filter conditions are met and one where they're not. The DataFrames should be exact opposites, in effect. However I can't seem to use the tilde operator in the way I assumed I could.

A reproducible example:

```
raw_data = {
    'id': ['s1', 's2', 's1', 's4', 's2', 's5', 's4', 's2'], 
    'car': ['ford', 'bmw', 'ford', 'mazda', 'ford', 'bmw', 'audi', 'bmw']}

df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns= ['id', 'car'])

values1 = ['s1', 's2']
values2 = ['bmw', 'ford']
df_a[(df_a['id'].isin(values1)) & (df_a['car'].isin(values2))]
```

Returns this:

```
    id  car
0   s1  ford
1   s2  bmw
2   s1  ford
4   s2  ford
7   s2  bmw
```

Which is correct. But if try to reverse that using:

`df_a[~(df_a['id'].isin(values1)) & (df_a['car'].isin(values2))]`

I get:

```
    id  car
5   s5  bmw
```

Which is not the inverse. I've tried adding a second tilde to the second filter but can't make it work. Where am I going wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need additional parentheses:

```
In [411]:
df_a[~((df_a['id'].isin(values1)) & (df_a['car'].isin(values2)))]
#     ^                                                        ^
Out[411]:
   id    car
3  s4  mazda
5  s5    bmw
6  s4   audi
```

What you did was invert only the first condition.

Comment: fwiw, I was having a similar problem with only a single condition, and I think this is different from the old behavior. your solution fixed it though, so thanks for that.

Comment: well, with the new pandas update (tried in 1.5.1), tilde won't work

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would have been to add a ~ to the second filter as you mentioned in your question. However you would have to change the 'and' operator to an 'or' operator. Here is a summary of the different scenarios.

EdChum answer = ~(A & B) = ~A | ~B = my answer

What you did was ~A & B and what you refered to as adding a ~ to the second filter was ~A & ~B, which is equivalent of ~(A | B). Where ~ = 'not', & = 'and', | = 'or'.

This link might help explain the reason for this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

EDIT:

Thank you AlexK for the suggestion, here is the actual code:

```py
In[6]: df_a[~(df_a['id'].isin(values1)) | ~(df_a['car'].isin(values2))]
#           ^                             ^ 
Out[6]: 
   id    car
3  s4  mazda
5  s5    bmw
6  s4   audi
```

Comment: Please add the actual code and output to your answer.  (+1 for explaining the logic)