# Delete string from dataframe with condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data

```
                                          event_address           event_time  
0      https://mail.yandex.ru/clck=2230&uid=1189231...  2016-06-14 03:05:19   
1      https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230&uid=1189231...  2016-06-14 03:05:23   
2      https://mail.yandex.ru/clck=2230&uid=1189231...  2016-06-14 03:05:24   
3        http://mail.yandex.ru/?win=219&clid=2257587-216  2016-06-14 03:04:52   
4       https://mail.yandex.ru/?win=219&clid=2257587-216  2016-06-14 03:04:52   
5                     https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230  2016-06-14 03:05:12   
6      https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230&uid=1189231...  2016-06-14 03:05:25
```

I want to delete str, where `url` contain `yandex.ru/clck`.
Desire output

```
                                          event_address           event_time    
1      https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230&uid=1189231...  2016-06-14 03:05:23      
3        http://mail.yandex.ru/?win=219&clid=2257587-216  2016-06-14 03:04:52   
4       https://mail.yandex.ru/?win=219&clid=2257587-216  2016-06-14 03:04:52   
5                     https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230  2016-06-14 03:05:12   
6      https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230&uid=1189231...  2016-06-14 03:05:25
```

I try use `~df[df.event_address.str.contains("yandex.ru/clck")]`but it return

`TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'unicode'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939552/pandas-using-the-tilde-operator-to-return-inverse-data-with-two-filters

Comment: And of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991058/how-to-iterating-string-in-df-using-python with just a `~` at the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df[~df.event_address.str.contains(r"yandex.ru/clck")]
```

demo:

```
In [167]: df[~df.event_address.str.contains(r"yandex.ru/clck")]
Out[167]:
                                      event_address
1    https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230&uid=1189231
3   http://mail.yandex.ru/?win=219&clid=2257587-216
4  https://mail.yandex.ru/?win=219&clid=2257587-216
5                https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230
6    https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230&uid=1189231

In [168]: df
Out[168]:
                                      event_address
0      https://mail.yandex.ru/clck=2230&uid=1189231
1    https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230&uid=1189231
2      https://mail.yandex.ru/clck=2230&uid=1189231
3   http://mail.yandex.ru/?win=219&clid=2257587-216
4  https://mail.yandex.ru/?win=219&clid=2257587-216
5                https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230
6    https://mail.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=2230&uid=1189231
```

Comment: @ldevyataykina, yes, it does - see the demo in my answer

Comment: I loved these comments! @Idevyataykina don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: @ysearka, sometimes, When the correct answer is ready, I can't do it, because It should take about 20 minutes after answer. Acception is done)